# Koszul Duality and Andre-Quillen homology relationship

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, operads

This may be a very open ended question but what is the relationship between koszul duality and Andre-Quillen homology? For example if I consider the André-Quillen homology $AQ_k(B)$ of an associative differential (positively) graded $R$-algebra then there is a grading on $AQ_k(B)$ which we may denote as $AQ_{k,n}(B)$. Now if I define $B$ to be koszul when $AQ_{k,n}(B) = 0$ for all $k\neq n$ is this the same as the usual definition of koszulness using $Ext$/$Tor$? Has this been studied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix up André--Quillen homology and Quillen homology. One is the derived functor of derivations, the other of *indecomposables*.

You want the latter, and then Koszulness is defined by the vanishing of $(d-1,w)$ terms ($d$ is the homological degree, $w$ the weight degree) with $d-1\neq w$, since there is a shift with respect to the usual grading for $\operatorname{Tor}$: $s^{-1}\operatorname{Tor}$ is Quillen homology, with the same weight grading, where $s^{-1}$ is the desuspension.

The extra grading for André--Quillen homology is useful, but for different reasons and related to deducing statements about deformations, for example see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01421).

Comment: Hmm. Ok. What do you mean by $s^{-1}Tor$ is Quillen homology? Do you have a recommended source to learn more about Quillen homology?

Comment: @joe I mean that if $A$ is an augmented $k$-algebra, for example, then its Quillen homology groups $H^Q_d(A)$ are isomorphic with $\mathrm{Tor}_{d+1}(k,k)$. This happens with other algebraic gadgets, where you now replace "Tor" with "the homology of the bar construction". Indeed, it is almost tautological once you know that $\Omega BA$ is a model for $A$, for then the derived indecomposables are given by $s^{-1}\overline{BA}$. In other words, if an algebraic gadget has a "bar-cobar" formalism coming from Koszul duality, then the bar functor gives you Quillen homology, up to a shift.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you @Pedro!! That is helpful :)